# Can Amazon Alexa Skills Kit (ASK) detect where it was interrupted (if it was)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I want to write an Alexa skill that would read a list of items out to me and let me interrupt when I wanted and have the backend know where I was in the list that was interrupted.

For example:

Me: Find me a news story about pigs. 
Alexa: I found 4 news stories about pigs.  The first is titled 'James the pig goes to Mexico', the second is titled 'Pig Escapes Local Farm' [I interrupt]
Me: Tell me about that.
Alexa: The article is by James Watson, is dated today, and reads, "Johnny the Potbelly Pig found a hole in the fence and..."

I can't find anything to indicate that my code can know where an interruption occurs.  Am I missing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are correct: the ASK does not provide any way to know when you were interrupted, however, this is all happening in real-time so you could figure it out by observing the amount of time that passes between doing the first ASK 'tell' (ie. where you call context.success( response )), and when you receive the "Tell me that" intent.

Note that the time it takes to read in US-en could be different then for US-gb, so you'll have to do separate calibrations.  Also, you might have to add some pauses into your speech text to improve accuracy since there will of course be some variability in the results due to processing times.

If you are using a service like AWS Lambda or Google App Engine that add extra latency when there are no warm instances available, then you will probably need to take that into account.

Comment: Great suggestions, thank you.  Clever work around.  I'll mark this as the accepted answer if no one suggests it is incorrect in the next day or two.

Comment: I concur with this answer. I had an app where I wanted to work out the interruption point. My plan was to clock how fast Alexa reads a standard passage of text. Divide that by the number of characters in the text, anduse that as a rough estimate to calculate how far it had read before the interruption. (Minus latency, as Tom points out).